# Javascript sync and async processes priority

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, process

I was researching about javascript's async behaviour despite being single-threaded and I came after a comment stating that for this code:

```
request(..., function (error, response, body)  
    console.log('foo);  
});  
    callAComputationallyIntensiveSynchronousFunctionThatTakesSixHoursToExecute();  
console.log('bar');
```

> 'bar' will still come before 'foo' because Javascript always finishes the currently executing function first. An event will never interrupt a function.

I understand that a synchronous function execution has a higher priority over events, but I don't understand why 'bar' will be printed before 'foo'. From my reading, the async call should be made, and after that to fill the dead time before response is ready, it goes on and processes the other lines of code until it is ready, and then it should execute the callback function for the response and after that return to processing the code and so on.

The example above however states that even if the response would be ready long before the synchronous function finishes from executing, it still goes on and execute the next line of code. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, everything is a function. There is no differentiation between a synchronous and an asynchronous function.
The only difference is the way you call these functions. So "sync"/"async" is an abstract concept for programmers which makes it easier to communicate.

**How JavaScript actually works:**

JavaScript has a queue of "functions" that are waiting to be executed. Everytime you create a new "asynchronous function", you add it to this queue. This happens, for example, when you do a `setTimeout()`, an ajax call, or simply a DOM-event like "onClick" triggered by the browser.

If a specific function is executed in JS, it will never be interrupted - it runs until it finished (returned). Only afterwards, the runtime (browser) takes a look at the queue, decides which function should be executed next, and then calls it - waiting it to be finished.

In your example above, the browser is currently executing the function that will print "bar". This execution cannot be interrupted before it finished, therefore "bar" is printed first. During the execution, however, a new asynchronous function is created and pushed to the execution-queue. Only after "bar" has been printed, the runtime will look in the queue, find the "foo"-function and execute it.

A negative side effect of this are long-running tasks. While such a function is executed, nothing else can be done by the browser. Not even rendering/updating the page. So if you have a piece of code that runs for, say, 10 seconds, the user cannot interact with the website until the function finished. The reason for that is that all user events, like mouse movenent, clicks and scroll events are queued and cannot be handled until the thread finishes the long running Task.

**Multithreading with JavaScript**

With HTML5, JavaScript now has the opportunity to use multiple threads using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) though. But this is an entirely different topic and out of scope for this question. Just remember that it is theoretically possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think you might misunderstood something in the code, however I'm not sure. The `console.log('bar')` follows the computationalHeavyFunction, and it's not the effect of the function. From what you say, I understand that after finishing the 'synchronous' function, it should take a look at the queue and see that the request is waiting to be executed, as the parser didn't reach the console.log('bar') instruction to add it to the queue. More over, how does the runtime decide which function in the queue to choose next?

Comment: Not quite. For example an _ajax call_ really is asynchronous, it is run in its own thread. In the meanwhile the browser continues the original script, and finally moves the control to a user (and the event queue). When the ajax thread is ready, the JS callback is executed, which reserves the "only" thread for the browser.

Comment: After discussing this answer a little bit more with some colleague, I think I *fully* understand now how this works. Scripts are in their way functions, and they are the first to be added to the queue, and after that it begins executing and add new 'async' functions to the queue, while continuing to execute the remaining function. Only after the machine finishes executing the current queue function, in this case the script itself, it would look at the queue and decide which function to execute next (maybe the request callback, or other script) not after every function call as I supposed.

Comment: @Andu Yes, it follows the computationally heavy function. So it is only printed after 6 hours. During these 6 hours, the "foo" function is waiting in the queue, and is started after "bar" has been printed.

Comment: @Teemu Correct, HTTP requests are one of the few things browsers actually execute in the background in parallel. But that's a browser detail - from the perspective of JavaScript, the Ajax-call's response is received via a normal callback function that runs on the main UI thread - hence it is not executed if a 6-hour job is currently in progress.

Comment: Yes, that's what I also tried to say with "_reserves the "only" thread_".